# How to make text moving/changing when click next?

Tags: javascript, php, html

i wan to make a web about toefl test. in one page, that is display a login form. so in bottom theres in a statement "not register? register now". i want to make, if i click "register now" statement, the login form will be change to register form. it is happen in one page. help me please

```
     <form method="POST" action="proseslogin.php">
            <table>
              <table>
                <tr>
                <td><input style="width:300px; height:30px; border:3px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS'; font-size:14px;" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input style="width:300px; height:30px; border:1px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS'; font-size:14px;"type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><br></td></tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input style="width:200px; height:30px; border:1px; font-family:'Trebuchet MS'; font-size:14px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </form>

<h3>Login <br><span>Not Register?</span> <a href="index_2.html">Register Now</a></h3>
```

Comment: add some action (for example add class with different position). Ideal is [jquery.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/). See also [onclick using target](http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-trigger-css3-transitions-on-click-using-target/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be solved via javascript. There are many ways to this, and one of the most simple soulotions is something like this:

In the html, you can make two forms, and put the js-code inside a `<script>`-tag:

```
<form method="POST" action="proseslogin.php" id="login-form">
  Your login form
  <input type="submit" value="Login"><br><br>
  <span>Not Register?</span> <a href="#" onclick="showRegisterForm()">Register Now</a>
</form>

<form method="POST" action="prosesregister.php" id="register-form" style="display:none">
  Your register form
</form>

<script>
  var showRegisterForm = function() {
    document.getElementById("login-form").setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    document.getElementById("register-form").setAttribute("style", "display:block");
  }
</script>
```

Working js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjespe/42pjtvpa/

Comment: thankyou, where i put javascript code? in html body?

Comment: There are several ways to attach javascript code, one alternative is to put it inside a <script> tag in the body.

Comment: I added a link to a working jsfiddle. So you can see how it can be done.

Comment: i make the display in one hmtl, that is named index.html. but i devide it on 3 page. first page is 'home', second page is 'about', and in last page is login/register form.

Comment: no the problem is, when i click 'register now' i will take to first page. so i must scroll to third page. how it can be display directly on third page?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but if you want to scroll to a specific point on the page you can put `id="something"` on the element you want to scroll to, and make a link like this `<a href="#something">Click here</a>`. When that link is tapped, the browser will go to the element with id `something`

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, you are supposed to click the "accept" check mark. Welcome to stack overflow.